# How to migrate project eclipse with library openCV to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have problem with import eclipse project with openCV library to android studio
when importing the project as mention https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html
google guide 
I face to this error

- Project Sample - face-detection:C:\Android\And\eyetracker-master\project.properties:
  Library reference ....\OpenCV-2.4.0\ could not be found
  Path is C:\Android\And\eyetracker-master....\OpenCV-2.4.0 which resolves to C:\Android\OpenCV-2.4.0

Comment: The error says it cannot find OpenCV-2.4.0 . This means that it's missing. Did you go to AS and go File>New>Import Project ?

Comment: Yes but i dont know how to add library before build a gradle ??

Comment: Migration to android studio,eclipse project does't have gradle.

Comment: Ok, but if you go New>Import Project , AS will do everything for you.

Comment: I agree with you but you can see(in error) should be add opencv before migration and i dont know how is it ??

Comment: You don't need to add anything :\

Comment: Maybe you can do it ??

Comment: Woah... Calm down. I'm going to ask you one last time, did you Try File>New>Import Project ?

Comment: Yes buddy iam calm,question have link that google descripe how to import project and i use it but...